# How can get get computer hostname in other network segment ?

Tags: java, networking, hostname

I can get hostname by ip using the method below:
(if we are in the same network segment----in case my IP is 10.167.10.2,other's ip is 10.167.10.5)

InetAddress add= InetAddress.getByName(ip);

String hostname=add.getHostName();

but I can't get hostname if the ip in other network segment---in case my IP is 10.167.10.2,other's ip is 10.167.13.5
the return is 10.167.13.5,not the computer's hostname

and when I am using C# ,the class DNS has the methed GetHostByAddress(),I can get every hostname by ip mentioned above using this method.

Our computers are in a domain。
I'm using windows XP,JAVA 1.6
How can I get computer hostname in other network segment?
                                              Thank you!

Comment: Does your company control both network segments? If yes, then I think that the key point is "Our computers are in a domain," and would guess (thus not an answer) that C# will go to the domain controller to ask for reverse-IP lookup. Doing the same with DNS requires PTR records, and a Windows shop might not have configured this (again guessing).

Answer (score -1):

[IPHostEntry Example](http://www.anyang-window.com.cn/tag/network/page/10/)

Try this site

Comment: Posting a link to off-site code isn't really the point of SO.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.